# How can VS2017 + Resharper surround selection with quotes when open quote typed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I use Visual Studio 2017 with Resharper Ultimate 2018.1 on Windows 10 to assist my coding in C#.

I enabled "Surround selection on typing a brace or paranthesis" under Resharper options. It now surrounds the selected text with `()` if I type `(` or with `{}` if I type `{`.

I want this behavior to act similar for single quotes, double quotes and braces as in `'selection'`, `"selection"`, `[selection]`.

All the solutions I found online use some sort of keyboard shortcut or context menu actions. It is too cumbersome to use combo keys or a mouse action to simply surround a code piece with quotes. Visual Studio for Mac supports this feature out of box. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Resharper->Options->Environment->Intellisense->Completion Behavior what do you have checked for "Automatically complete single item with:"?  Also what do you have selcted for Intellisense->General?  I have VS2017 and Resharper 2017.2 and the behavior you are looking for seems to work ok.  I'll update to 2018 and see if I have the same problem.

Comment: Nevermind, misunderstood the question.  I see the issue now.  Will submit an answer if i find one

Comment: Interestingly, Rider has an option to "Surround selection on typing quote or brace," but it doesn't seem to work for standard quotes (`"`).  It works for backticks (`\``), though.  So even if ReSharper supposedly supports this feature, it may be broken at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a template in Resharper for that
Go to ReSharper -> Tools -> Template Explorer -> Surround Templates -> C#
and create new

[image]

[image]

Now if you go to your code and type

var a = 4444;
Then select 4444 and press Ctrl E+ Ctrl U you will see the following

[image]

The result is

var a = "4444";

Comment: Thanks for the response but as I simply said, I want to use `"` key instead of key combinations of Ctrl and letters.

Answer (score 0):

Select your text and press double quote `"`, which is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> on my keyboard, and you'll get quotes around your selection.

It doesn't seem to work with single quote `'`. Or at least, I couldn't figure it out.